# Remapping special keys on a Logitech keyboard

Tags: windows-7, remapping, logitech-keyboard

I just bought a new keyboard today, and to my surprise it doesn't include "Next/Previous track" keys, although it has other media keys. It also has useless keys like "Home" which brings up the web browser. Or well, it's not actually the "Home" key, it's a special key on the keyboard with a house on it - no idea what it's called. Anyway, so I'd like to remap the "House" key to "Next track".

I've tried three different remapping programs now and none of them seem to be working. I think the real problem is that it's a special key, so it's not included in any keyboard remapping applications.

The keyboard is a Logitech, can't seem to find the exact model though.

Any tips?

Comment: Have you tried in the SetPoint software?  (Also the exact model should be written on a label on the bottom.)

Comment: I'll give that a shot, thanks. I found the model now, well hidden under the keyboard, hehe. I'll update after i've tried it.

Comment: I just installed it, and it doesn't show any settings at all for the keyboard. I've got a logitech mouse aswell, and it only shows settings for that. :/

Comment: Under what operating system?

Comment: Windows 7 Professional, 86-bit

Comment: @Gilles: If not named, it's always the "default". Wow, I haven't seen anything that was 86-bit! I bet that *really* hums!

Comment: @Dennis, i didn't mention i was on Windows 7. Don't make a fool out of yourself.

Comment: @Dennis, confusing x86 for 86-bit is not THAT unusual.  You could be a little nicer in pointing out that 'x86' is the name of the processor instruction set, and means it's a 32-bit operating system.

Comment: @thedude: You should put a tag for your OS (either specific like `windows-7` or generic like `windows`), not just because the OS is vital information to answer your question, but also because some people filter on tags so you're missing out on potential answerers.

Comment: @Dennis: Ok, noted. On my machine, “default” in the boot menu is Debian stable, so that's what I'll assume. Seriously, I hope that by leaving comments on poorly informed posts I'll encourage people to post more information (an uphill battle, I know).

Comment: @Shinrai: On the other hand, when people mention the word size, it's usually 64. So the mystery is still open! (But I think this bit of info is useless here.)

Comment: @Gilles - Agreed that it's meaningless.  I was objecting to the tone - being condescending is not the way to make new users want to stick around.

Comment: Running OT here guys, can any of you provide me with something useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download and install [AutoHotkey_L](http://www.autohotkey.com/download/), let it associate with .ahk files
2. Grab the script called "Keyboard Hook - 90L" from [Scriptlet to find Scancode of a Key](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic22881.html) and save it somewhere, e.g. My Documents/keys.ahk
3. Navigate to the file you saved and double click it
4. Move the mouse over the "Keyboard Hook" window and press the button you want to map, e.g. Home key
5. Note the value in the Scan column (e.g. SC132)
6. Create your own .ahk script
7. Add the .ahk script to your Startup folder

Your script should contain e.g.

```
SC132::Send {Media_Next}
```

Or, you could map Windows+Left to previous track and Windows+Right to next track with this AutoHotkey script:

```
#Left::Send {Media_Prev}
#Right::Send {Media_Next}
```

Or this way works even if the window is hidden or minimized:

```
#Left::SendMessage, 0x319, 0, 0xC0000, , iTunes  
#Right::SendMessage, 0x319, 0, 0xB0000, , iTunes
```

but you have to Google to find out the values like 0xC0000.

Some other useful shortcuts:

```
#Up::Send {Volume_Up}
;#Up::SoundSetWaveVolume, +20
#Down::Send {Volume_Down}
;#Down::SoundSetWaveVolume, -20

;#NumpadIns::Send {Media_Play_Pause}
;#Numpad0::Send {Media_Play_Pause}
#Ins::SendMessage, 0x319, 0, 0xE0000, , iTunes
#Del::Send {Volume_Mute}
#NumpadIns::SendMessage, 0x319, 0, 0xE0000, , iTunes
#Numpad0::SendMessage, 0x319, 0, 0xE0000, , iTunes

; works on Vista without IntelliType
#NumpadDot::Send {Volume_Mute}
#NumpadDel::Send {Volume_Mute}
; works on Vista with IntelliType when AutoHotKey.exe is in Windows XP mode
;#NumpadDot::SoundSet, +1, , mute
;#NumpadDel::SoundSet, +1, , mute
```

See the [AutoHotkey docs](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) for more details.

Comment: That was what i had in mind when i first wanted to remap the key, thanks. The "keyboard-hook" script doesn't give me the correct code though. All the "special keys" on the keyboard shows as "SC000". Any idea on how to find out the actual code of it?

Comment: It might actually help to remove all Logitech software.  Of course, if you're using a Logitech mouse, you might lose any special functionality.